# How do you see an author of a directory?

Tags: command-line

I need to know. Please. I have a test soon.

Comment: What do you mean? Owner or Creator of directory?

Comment: it's very unclear what you mean. You can view the OWNER of a directory by `ls -l /path/to/` the directory (without the directory itself). You'll get something like `drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 12288 Jun 28 15:19` where the first letters are the permissions and `root root` means folder/file owned by user root and group root

Answer (score 3):

Linux file systems don't record the creator of files. They do however record the *owner* and the *owner group* which you can view with tools like

- `ls -ld`
- `getfacl`
- `stat`